# How to confugure csproj to setup /p:DebugType=full?

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

We can generate sdandard pdb using `dotnet test /p:DebugType=full blabla\Vse.AdminkaV1.Injected.NETStandard.Test.csproj` (core projects by default generate portable pdbs)

But how to save this option in csproj file?

Comment: Project > Properties > Compile tab > select the relevant configuration > Advanced button > "Debugging information" combobox.

Answer (score 4):

What I usually did is unload your project -> right click -> edit your .csproj -> here you can change your `debugtype`

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Exactly this method doesn't worked for me. On the changes in csproj   <DebugType>Full</DebugType> gone.I guess because it should be only under conditional PropertyGroup.

Comment: What do you mean? It's gone after you saved it or it's not there at the beginning.

Comment: Added manually it's gone after editing "Project Properties" in VS.